# Call helper method from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my `Predictions` model I created a method in `predictions_helper.rb` like this:

```
module PredictionsHelper

  def time_in_date(time, date)
    time.between(date..date+1.day)
  end
end
```

However, when I call it like this:

```
time_in_date(le.time, date)
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `time_in_date' for PredictionsHelper:Module
```

Comment: where and how do you call it?

Comment: BTW, helpers are **not** for being used from models. They're for views mainly (and, sometimes, controllers)

Comment: Within a model's method. The entire line looks like this `le = @last_estimation.select{|le| time_in_date(le.time, date)}.first`

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the easiest thing to do would be to include your module in your Predictions class

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PredictionsHelper
end
```

That will give you access to time_in_date

Answer (score 4):

The predictions_helper is within scope of the Predictions model, however, since you've put it inside of a module, you'll need to include that module.

So:

```
include PredictionsHelper
# code...
```

or

```
PredictionsHelper::time_in_date(le.time, date)
```