# Method calling helper method response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my helper that returns rows of results. I want to pass this to a method in my model which is called by another method.

Helper Method:

```
def transactions(account_id, start, finish)
  response = get_call('/Accounts/Statements/' + account_id.to_s + '/' + start + '/' + finish)
  response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  @transactions = response.map {|txn| Transaction.new(txn)}

  return @transactions
end
```

Model Method I wish to call helper method into:

```
def transaction
  ??
end
```

Model Method which requires the transaction method:

```
def to_pdf
  title = @account.name
  subtitle = "Account Statement: #{@month_name} #{@year}"
  StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, @transactions).render
end
```

In the initialise section of this method i have added:

```
@transactions = {}
```

The Prawn PDF is now being generated but without the rows of results. Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call helper method from model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261524/call-helper-method-from-model)

Comment: I see that you keep going with this "putting model code in helpers" approach. Don't know what's your rationale, but be warned, only problems await you on this path. This code does not belong in helpers. It performs an API call, so this makes it a resource/model.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your helpers from models using `ApplicationController.helpers` method:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.transactions(...)
```

This will solve your problem but, in my opinion, it would be much better, if you refactor your code and don't use helpers from model.